# pc powers on for a sec, then off for 5 secs, and repeat forever

Tags: hardware-failure

this seems to be a hardware related question.

My UPS broke down yesterday and it seems to have brought down a PC with it, which repeatedly tries to power on but never manages.

My findings:

- I tried a different PSU. the problem persists.
- I tried to remove everything fron the PSU (HD, GPU etc) and left only the motherboard power and the cpu power. The problem persists.
- I tried to remove the CPU power and the motherboard seems to start (so fans etc), but of course the cpu does not start now and I see no BIOS.
- I tried plugging everything back on apart from CPU power and the motherboard starts , but again the CPU does not start.

So it is not PSU, but it seems it is either motherboard, or CPU, or CPU power electronics . right?
is there a way to tell what it is?

Comment: I have had this. It was the CPU for me

Comment: Did you tried to remove the CMOS battery and clear CMOS(reset BIOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your eliminations, it's either the MB or CPU (the CPU power electronics in most systems are part of the MB).  My experience is that unless the machine is almost new, you wind up replacing both together (along with RAM) anyway, so that's what I'd recommend.

Given that the PSU comes up without the CPU power connected, the CPU is the most likely culprit, but unless you're tied for some reason to using the same MB/CPU combination, it's probably more sensible to shop for a good deal on a MB/CPU/RAM bundle that gives the same or better performance, and save your time ordering and installing part -- which may damage each other if you've guessed wrong.